Are timers in Node.js part of event-driven architecture? Do they emit events when they expire?
I was wondering if timers are actually part of event-driven architecture in Node.js.
However, I haven't found anything mentioning it in the official Node.js documentation.
Does it actually emit any events on completion (like fs or http) or not?

I'm 99% sure that they do not emit any events, so are not part of this architecture. I'm just confused since some tutorials mentioned that timers do emit some events.

If you're getting mixed up over language used in some tutorials, I think it'd be better to quote and link the tutorial(s) in the question. Then maybe it can be clarified. By the looks of the docs, it looks like they do not emit events, but you can attach callbacks to them or use the Promises API.
